# Get number of pixels of certain color in Android Studio with OpenCv

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio

I'm writing a fairly simple app that will, in real-time, tell the user how many pixels there are above a certain color value in an image.

That is, it takes preview images from the camera and analyses them as the user move the camera around.

Right now, I have this code, which technically works:

```
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    Rect sample = new Rect();
    Mat sampleRegionRgba;

    numPixs = 0;
    boundary.add(100); boundary.add(100);boundary.add(100);

    int cols = mRgba.cols();
    int rows = mRgba.rows();

    double yLow = (double)mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight() * 0.2401961;
    double yHigh = (double)mOpenCvCameraView.getHeight() * 0.7696078;

    double xScale = (double)cols / (double)mOpenCvCameraView.getWidth();
    double yScale = (double)rows / (yHigh-yLow);

    int tmpX;
    int tmpY;

    for (int x = 0; x < cols-6; x++) {
        for (int y = (int)yLow; y < yHigh-6; y++){

            tmpX = (int)((double)x * xScale);

            tmpY = (int)((double)y * yScale);

            sample.x = tmpX+3;
            sample.y = tmpY+3;



            sample.width = 2;
            sample.height = 2;

            sampleRegionRgba = mRgba.submat(sample);
            Mat sampleRegionHsv = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(sampleRegionRgba, sampleRegionHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL);

            mBlobColorHsv = Core.sumElems(sampleRegionHsv);
            int pointCount = sample.width * sample.height;
            for (int i = 0; i < mBlobColorHsv.val.length; i++){
                mBlobColorHsv.val[i] /= pointCount;
            }

            mBlobColorRgba = convertScalarToRgba(mBlobColorHsv);

//                System.out.println(mBlobColorRgba.toString());

            if (mBlobColorRgba.val[0] > boundary.get(0)
                    && mBlobColorRgba.val[1] > boundary.get(1)
                    && mBlobColorRgba.val[2] > boundary.get(2)){
                numPixs += 1;
            }


//                System.out.println(sampleRegionRgba.toString());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("number of pixels above boundary: "+Integer.toString(numPixs));

    massflow = m*(Math.pow(numPixs,.25))+b;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            massflow_text.setText("Massflow: "+Double.valueOf(massflow));
        }
    });
```

While this code works, it takes about 6 seconds to run for each image.

I'd like it to have a much more reasonable frame rate. I know this can be done with numpy (I've done it with np.where()). Is it possible with Java/OpenCv/Android Studio ?

Comment: You can basically replace all this code with `inrange` to segment the color you need, and `countNonZero` on the produced mask

Comment: great, that works beautifully! Thanks, and sorry for the late reply, I've been away from my computer for a while.